# P/Invoke, C# returns a string to native code

Tags: pinvoke

My code works, but I am afraid of the memory within P/Invoke.

Here is the delegate I will call from native C++ code.

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public delegate string CommandCallbackDelegate([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string command
    , [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string arg1
    , [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string arg2
    );
```

And in C#, I passed the delegate to native DLL.

```
private static GCHandle _gcHandle;
public static void RegisterCommandCallback(CommandCallbackDelegate fun) { _gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(fun);

    if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        RegisterCommandCallback_x64(fun);
    else
        RegisterCommandCallback_x86(fun);
}
```

And in the native DLL, after I get the function pointer, I can call the method successfully and get the returned `String` from C#.

```
typedef LPCWSTR (WINAPI* PFN_CommandCallback)( LPCWSTR wszCommand, LPCWSTR wszArg1, LPCWSTR wszArg2);
PFN_CommandCallback g_pfnCommandCallback = ....;

LPCWSTR wszRet = g_pfnCommandCallback( L"CMD", L"ARG1", L"ARG2");
```

As you can see, the C# method returns `String` to the native DLL, I am not sure if the returned unmanaged memory is repleased by GC.

Although my above code works, I am afraid it is accessing the memory which is just released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, the pinvoke marshaller allocates the string return value with the shared COM allocator. So your native code should call `CoTaskMemFree` on the pointer that the native DLL returns. And so you may need to take a copy of the contents before you free the memory!

As an aside, there's no need to decorate the parameters with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]` since that just re-states the default. Your code would be easier to read with that removed.